# How to convert a text document into .md(markdown) file

Tags: javascript

Create a markdown file by using a text file. so the input file for the code should be .txt file and the expected output should be the .md file with the content of the text file.
steps:

1. Take a text file called doc.txt
2. Convert the file into doc.md

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour], look around, and read the [help], esp. *[ask]*. Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and **give it a try**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it, [search](/help/searching) [thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:stackoverflow.com), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help. [More here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/).

Comment: Should the contents of doc.md be the same as doc.txt? Or different? Could you edit the question to give an example of a simple doc.txt and doc.md, please?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework, please at least attempt the problem before asking for help

Answer (score 1):

In python , you can achieve this through **shutil** library , using this below two lines of code.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile("testcopy.txt", "testcopy.md")
```

In Javascript , you can try with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-txt npm package or else you can use this online converters too https://cloudconvert.com/txt-to-md